# Android: what's the best view to use when making an image tile grid view?

Tags: android, android-layout, picasso

Got some good feedback. Originally wanted infinite scroll. Removed it. I am also an interested in a solution with pagination or that just handles a simple case of the first 20 results to start. The main thing I want to know is the best types of views to use. Question was very vague at first. Narrowed the scope of it, too.

I want a view that fills the phone or tablet's screen with tiled images from an api.

How I'm thinking about doing this:

- putting a GridView in my layout
- using the Picasso library by Square to load the images (possibly do more, not sure what it can do for me)
- making an adapter to the GridView
- doing a query to my api (in this case getting popular movies)
- processing the query results and turning them into an ArrayList of Strings or Uris with the image locations (for popular movie posters)
- passing the list to the adapter to the GridView so it can show the images.

I don't I know enough about Android to think this through fully yet. I'm in the process of learning.

Any suggestions for better design, tutorials on similar things, or things that may make this easier/better?

Thanks!

Comment: GridView -> I would use RecyclerView. *ArrayList of Strings or Uri*, check the response and create a Model class out of the response instead of passing only *string* or *uri*. my 2cents

Comment: Make that an answer so I can choose it? If you vote this down, maybe suggest a forum I can move this post to as well.

Comment: Adding to the previous comment, you should learn about the concept of pagination. *Make that an answer so I can choose it*, I haven't an answer for. The comment is enough. *If you voted this down*, I didn't.

Comment: Thanks, your answer was really good. Made my question less vague to clarify what I was looking for.